# What was the process for joining the military in Canada for WW2 and what are the different associated records?

Tags: military-records, world-war-2, canada

If someone in Canada wanted to join in on World War 2 what was the process, requirements, and associated records for each step?

For example, did they have to do informal training first or do an oath first etc. ? What was the full process and associated records?

This would be for a non-officer who has no previous military experience. I'm interested in both voluntary and conscription paths although I think my ancestor did it voluntarily.

Comment: Since the question has been edited to be about WW2 only and not WW1, I'm deleting the comments which are about WW1.

Comment: Where have you looked so far?  Including your prior research may help focus this to a single question and prevent potential answerers retracing your steps.

Comment: @PolyGeo I am totally new to this so I just did a quick Google search and didn't find anything helpful. I tried to look on the veteran affairs website but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 3):

There are several paths of research that come to mind:

- 1939-1945 Canadian newspapers with enlistment advertisments and articles explaining the process to potential recruits
- biographies, memoirs, and war diaries of Canadian soldiers
- military history websites, such as the [Canadian War Museum](https://www.warmuseum.ca/home/) or Regimental sites

The Canadian War Museum has a section titled [Democracy at War: Canadian Newspapers and the Second World War](https://www.warmuseum.ca/cwm/exhibitions/newspapers/intro_e.html) "A searchable archive of more than 144,000 newspaper articles and editorials documenting every aspect of the war."

- Example: [IT CAN HAPPEN HERE AND IT DEPENDS ON YOU AND ME](https://collections.museedelhistoire.ca/warclip/objects/common/webmedia.php?irn=5068920), Hamilton Spectator, 1942/05/28 (pdf file, 3 pages)

Libraries and Archives Canada includes sample documents in their [Service Files of the Second World War - War Dead, 1939-1947](http://www.bac-lac.gc.ca/eng/discover/military-heritage/second-world-war/second-world-war-dead-1939-1947/Pages/files-second-war-dead.aspx)

A list of [Canadian infantry regiments](https://www.canada.ca/en/department-national-defence/services/military-history/history-heritage/official-military-history-lineages/lineages/infantry-regiments.html) has links to pages with more detail